# iPad rotate from portrait to landscape

Tags: ipad, rotation, landscape, portrait

My view is originally in landscape mode. when a button is taped, a view opens in portrait mode and everything is find upto this point. the problem is when I go back from that view to the root view the view won't rotate correctly. here is the code I use to rotate the view from portrait to landscape,

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

//rotate the page to lansscape
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90*0.0174532925);
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);

[self.navigationController.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];

self.navigationController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;    
self.navigationController.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.navigationController.view.center  = CGPointMake (384.0, 544.0);

[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

here is a screen shot of the root page in landscape mode after returning from the portrait page,

[image]

this is how it should look like

[image]

Comment: Check your xib orientation view.

Comment: of course one it's landscape!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

//rotate the page to lansscape
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90*0.0174532925);
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);

[self.navigationController.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];

self.navigationController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;    
self.navigationController.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+64);
self.navigationController.view.center  = CGPointMake (384.0, 512.0);

[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

}
```

the thing that i had to play around to adjust the landscape view that was appearing after this view that is in portrait mode disappears was this,

```
self.navigationController.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+64);
self.navigationController.view.center  = CGPointMake (384.0, 512.0);
```

I played around with the center point and the frame height to adjust it.